# What determines the accuracy of the current location in the Maps app?

Tags: windows-8

Checking my location using the Maps app, I see that it identifies my location incorrectly by hundreds of miles.

What determines the accuracy of the location as identified by the Maps app?

Comment: Edited with more information to make it clear.

Comment: It maybe guessing your location based on the where the server of your ISP is located. I am based in Mumbai and my location shows somewhere in the eastern part of the company. The main server of the ISP is based there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accuracy largely depends upon the hardware you are running on, and your network connections:

1. GPS and A-GPS have a resolution of 5-7m at best
2. Wireless Network-based resolution is usually a few hundred metres.

If you are on a device **without the above hardware**, you will see IP-based positioning, which could be very inaccurate, as your ISP's internet-facing server could be some-place else entirely.

Comment: Correct, I was using IP based positioning. I see marginal difference with Wifi. thanks!